# Why does Socket.Select(...) take IList and not (also) IList<Socket>?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, css-selectors

I'm implementing some networking code using the selector pattern in C# / .NET 3.5. However, I was surprised to find that the `Select` method takes nongeneric `IList`'s rather than  `IList<Socket>`'s. It says clearly in the help documentation though that a list of sockets is expected here and nothing else.

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.select.aspx):

> Supported in: 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0

That would have been a pretty interesting signature in .NET 1.0...

The signature can't be changed without breaking existing callers. They could have added an overload, but I'm not sure it would have helped very much - if you'd tried to use the "new" overload with the wrong argument types (e.g. `List<string>` instead of `List<Socket>`) it would just have bound to the old overload.

Comment: Thanks. The explanation about why they couldn't just have added an additional overload is what I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

`Socket.Select` (which I assume you mean by Select) is a method that was already present in .NET 1.0, and Microsoft apparently never bothered to update it, probably because it is a quaint and seldom-used API.

Comment: Provide an overload and decorate the original function with `ObsoleteAttribute`.